# Переписать из jQuery в PHP (DOMDocument)

Tags: jquery, php, dom

Привет, как бы глупо не звучал заголовок, но он таков :( Помогите разобраться с DOMDocument или с чем угодно, любой библиотекой с которой проще. Я начал так:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://anyurl.com/');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($html);
```

и всё. к сожалению с ООП в PHP не работал. Может у кого-то будет свободная минутка подсказать, мне нужно реализовать примерно такое:

```
var obj = $('.articles .list').eq('$id');
obj.find('a').text('$link_txt').attr('href','$href').addClass('bold');
obj.find('span').text('$pasn_txt');

$('.navbar a').each(function(){
  var kh = $(this).attr('href');
  if (kh == '#') { $(this).attr('href', kh+'456.html'); }
});

$('.share-list').hide();
```

У меня сейчас это тупо "эвалится" и я понимаю что совсем не дело, но не знаю с чего начать :( подскажите если это не очень трудно и времязатратно....

Comment: Может [phpQuery][1] тут поможет? Хотя, я скорее всего не совсем понял вашу задачу, но всё же...

   [1]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/

Comment: Задача минимум: превратить относительные пути в абсолютные у src, имея на руках $base_url = 'superdomain.com/';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ройте в сторону preg_replace. 
В JS не больно то и силён, но как я понял Вам требуется найти элементы изменить стили и урлы в линках.

```
$ht = preg_replace('!<a href="'.$href.'">'.$link_text.'<\/a>!','!<a href="'.$href.'" class="bold">'.$link_text.'<\/a>!',$html)
```

Главное не забывайте проверить входящие переменные $href и $link_text.

Comment: Реально ли, с помощью preg_replace:
==============================================
1) Найти все атрибуты HREF тега A, внутри блока с классом .ALERT и поменять из значение на 'их значение' + '?124.php'

2) Найти все теги SPAN, внутри блока с классом .alert удалить html который там внутри и вставить свой, скажем '<b>123</b>'

Comment: Вполне реально.
Прочитайте следующие доки и сами сможет понять как сделать:

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

судя по документации, метод не тот у DOMDocument

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>"); 
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

loadHTML вместо loadXML